# how to call a function of super class from base class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, multiple-inheritance

Function from base class

```
open class ResultBase: ParametersBase<ResultBase.Fields, ResultBase>
{
    public enum Fields
    {
        case Value
        case Status
        case Message
        case ErrorMessages
        case WarningMessages
        case SuccessMessages
    }

    private var responseValue: Any?
    public var status = CoreResponseStatus.ok
    public var message: String?
    public var errorMessages = [CoreResponseBase]()
    public var warningMessages = [CoreResponseBase]()
    public var successMessages = [CoreResponseBase]()

    func from(dictionary: [AnyHashable: Any])
    {
        set(dictionary: dictionary)
        responseValue = value(forKey: .Value)

        if let value:Int = value(forKey: .Status) {
            status = CoreResponseStatus(rawValue: value) ?? CoreResponseStatus.ok
        }

        message = value(forKey: .Message)

        if let value:[[AnyHashable:Any]] = value(forKey: .ErrorMessages) {
            value.forEach { [weak self] (item) in
                self?.errorMessages.append(CoreResponseBase().from(dictionary: item))
            }
        }

        if let value:[[AnyHashable:Any]] = value(forKey: .WarningMessages) {
            value.forEach { [weak self] (item) in
                self?.warningMessages.append(CoreResponseBase().from(dictionary: item))
            }
        }

        if let value:[[AnyHashable:Any]] = value(forKey: .SuccessMessages) {
            value.forEach { [weak self] (item) in
                self?.successMessages.append(CoreResponseBase().from(dictionary: item))
            }
        }
    }

    func toDictionary() -> [AnyHashable: Any]
    {
        toDictionary = [AnyHashable: Any]()

        add(key: .Value, value: responseValue)
        add(key: .Status, value: status.rawValue)
        add(key: .Message, value: message)

        var errorMessages = [[AnyHashable: Any]]()
        for item in self.errorMessages
        {
            errorMessages.append(item.toDictionary())
        }
        add(key: .ErrorMessages, value: errorMessages)

        var warningMessages = [[AnyHashable: Any]]()
        for item in self.warningMessages
        {
            warningMessages.append(item.toDictionary())
        }
        add(key: .WarningMessages, value: warningMessages)

        var successMessages = [[AnyHashable: Any]]()
        for item in self.successMessages
        {
            successMessages.append(item.toDictionary())
        }
        add(key: .SuccessMessages, value: successMessages)

        return toDictionary
    }
}
```

Function from super class

```
open class AuthenticationService
{
    open class Authenticate: ParametersBase<Authenticate.Fields, Authenticate>
    {
        public enum Fields
        {
            case Expires
            case LoginName
            case Password
        }

        public var expires: String?
        public var loginName: String?
        public var password: String?

        override open func from(dictionary: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> Authenticate
        {
            set(dictionary: dictionary)
            let ret = Authenticate()

            ret.expires = value(forKey: .Expires)
            ret.loginName = value(forKey: .LoginName)
            ret.password = value(forKey: .Password)

            return ret
        }

        open func toDictionary() -> [AnyHashable: Any]
        {
            toDictionary = [AnyHashable: Any]()

            add(key: .Expires, value: expires)
            add(key: .LoginName, value: loginName)
            add(key: .Password, value: password)

            return toDictionary
        }
    }

    open class AuthenticateResponse: ResultBase
    {
        public var value: AuthToken?

        open override func from(dictionary: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> AuthenticateResponse
        {
            super.from(dictionary: dictionary)
            let ret = AuthenticateResponse()

            if let value:[AnyHashable:Any] = value(forKey: .Value)
            {
                ret.value = AuthToken().from(dictionary: value)
            }

            return ret
        }
    }
}
```

Here I want to create an object of baseClass let ret = AuthenticateResponse() and return the value from ret object not from super or self. In the current case ret returns the default assigned value and not the dictionary value but I want dictionary values from ret object.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. First, `AuthenticateResponse` is not the base class. The base class is `ResultBase`. Then, `override func from(dictionary: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> AuthenticateResponse` should not compile at all, because it does not override anything (different return type in base class)

Comment: You have overridden the function that is from the superclass. You are creating a hierarchy of super-> super-> Child.

Comment: I have updated my code. Now please take a look @AndreasOetjen